# Calling a method to fill a 2d array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, methods

I am a very new programmer, and have been struggling to write a method that can        take any 2D array and fill it with random integers from 1 to 15. I believe I managed to build my method correctly, but I can't seem to see how to then call my method to fill the array I made in main. (I would have just filled it in main right out, but I'm trying to practice methods as well.) Here is the code I have so far. I appreciate any help you all are able to give me, thanks!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Homework2
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,] myArray = new int[5,6];
    }

    public int[,] FillArray (int i, int j)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int[,] tempArray = new int[,]{};
        for (i = 0; i < tempArray.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < tempArray.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                tempArray[i, j] = rnd.Next(1, 15);
            }
        }
        return tempArray;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your method doesn't fill an array - it creates a new array. (It's also not at all clear what the parameters are meant to be for.)

If you want it to fill an existing array, you should have *that* as the parameter:

```
public static void FillArray(int[,] array)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            array[i, j] = rnd.Next(1, 15);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can call it from `Main` with:

```
FillArray(myArray);
```

Notes:

- We don't need to return anything, as the caller has already passed us a reference to the array to be filled
- I've made the method static as it doesn't need to access any state of a `Program` instance
- In general, creating a new `Random` instance "on demand" is a bad idea; read my [article on `Random`](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx) for more details

Comment: I believe the second `for` should be using `array`, not `tempArray`.

Comment: @DaveZych - You dare to question the all-knowing Jon Skeet? :)

Comment: @Tim nobody is immune to mistakes :)

Comment: @DaveZych - Yes, I know that.   Just couldn't resist the comment, given that it was a Jon Skeet(TM) answer :)

Comment: Thanks Jon! I appreciate all of the helpful insight as well. Just started on the article you sent me!

Comment: Another side note...if 15 is to be **included** in the possible values you want, then use `rnd.Next(1, 16);`.  See [Random.Next](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx): _Return Value - A 32-bit signed integer greater than or equal to minValue and less than maxValue; that is, the range of return values includes minValue but not maxValue._

Answer (score 0):

Simple technique is to make the use of Enumberable.Repeat() in C#. Check below code for 5 column and 10 row mattrix.

```
int[][] a = Enumerable.Repeat(Enumerable.Repeat(-1, 5).ToArray(), 10).ToArray();
for(int i =0; i < a.Length; i++)
{
   for(int j=0; j < a[0].Length; j++)
   {
       Console.Write($"{a[i][j]} \t");
   }
 Console.WriteLine();
}
```

> O/p:
>
> -1    -1  -1  -1  -1
> -1    -1  -1  -1  -1
> -1    -1  -1  -1  -1
> -1    -1  -1  -1  -1
> -1    -1  -1  -1  -1
> -1    -1  -1  -1  -1
> -1    -1  -1  -1  -1
> -1    -1  -1  -1  -1
> -1    -1  -1  -1  -1
> -1    -1  -1  -1  -1

See it in action!

https://rextester.com/SXU33123

Comment: This doesn't fill the array with random integers.